# create Service Account to install and run the services in system using c#

Tags: c#-3.0

I need to do the steps like this programmatically (https://support.servicenow.com/kb?id=kb_article_view&sysparm_article=KB0867669)

Comment: What have you tried so far and how did it go ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.